# Connection between Veneziano amplitude and Regge amplitude

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, s-matrix-theory

I have tried to read about Regge theory, and I continue to run my head against the Veneziano formula, which is said to produce correct Regge trajectories by eg. t'Hooft at page 6 here: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/stringnotes.pdf

What is the connection between that amplitude, and the Regge amplitude:
$$
A(s,t) \rightarrow \beta(t)s^{\alpha(t)} \text{   as  } s\rightarrow \infty
$$
which can be derived just from the analytical continuation of partial wave amplitudes?

Is at possible to show that one is a special case of the other? In particular, is the Veneziano amplitude just a special choice of $\beta$ given some physical assumptions, and can that choice be shown to be more or less general than others which, I assume, can also give correct Regge trajectories.

Comment: It follows from Stirling's formula that the Veneziano amplitude has the asymptotic behaviour $A(s,t) ~\sim~\Gamma(-\alpha(t))(- \alpha(s))^{\alpha(t)}$ for $s\rightarrow \infty$. Is that your question?